# How does one stop C-Cleaner from deleting the lists of Recent MS-Office files (WIN7, Office 2010, C-Clnr

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, ccleaner

Using C-Cleaner* under WIN7, I find it always deletes the lists of MS-Office 2010 "Recent files" ("Files" tab; Recent, enabling quick reopening of recently used files). As a result, it is tedious to reopen my regular files after a C-Clean.

I've tried  all the settings that look relevant, both those under Cleaner/Windows and Applications, and also those under Options.

Can anyone please advise me whether there is a way to avoid the loss of "Recent files" lists?

Advice appreciated - And thank you for reading to this point

- latest freeby-version of C-Cleaner (5.43.6522; 64-bit)

Comment: Yes, there should be a checkbox indicating you want to clear the recent list, make sure it’s unchecked.  If that doesn’t work uncheck all options for Office

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks - I'd been unable to find such a checkbox in C-Cleaner, having already tried unticking "Office2010", and in desperation, "Windows MS search" and "Windows MS M'g't Console". In Options/Advanced I’d *not* unticked “Enable Win Jump List Tasks”, just in case.  HOWEVER, at your prompting, I have found, at the lowest edge of the EXCEL/File-tab (rather than in C-Cleaner), a checkbox labelled “Quickly access this number of Recent Workbooks”, and that does seem to protect the file list from C-Clean. So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the CCleaner options > windows tab> under windows. Over here there is an option to unselect "recent documents". That should take care of this setting for you. It's shown here in the screenshot.

From their website:

"Recent Documents - This option clears the list Windows Explorer maintains of your most recently-opened files (see, for example, the My Recent Documents item on the Start menu)."

[image: screenshot]

Update: In case it's already unchecked then just try to enable it, run a scan, and then disable it, run another scan. It should help you reset the settings for this switch.

Comment: Dear Mugen, thanks for your careful and precise description of a possible solution to my problem. HOWEVER, I have to report that the identified tickbox was probably unticked before I posed the problem (even tho' I don't use IE, so I didn't expect that tickbox to be relevant). I will go back and remove my current solution to see if 'your' box gets re-ticked and then test that alone. As my routine files are large, each one seems to need a separate instance of Excel; if I use the Start Menu list, it tries to open the 2nd file in the first Excel instance, and usually the combination is too big.

Comment: Dear Mugen, I must admit that I'm puzzled - having unticked the Excel/FileTab/QuickAccess box, and leaving the WindowsExplorer RecentDocs still unticked (which seemed ineffective before I posed the question), it's now all behaving as you said it should. So thanks again, but you leave me puzzled as to why it wasn't behaving correctly in the first place.

Comment: That is really strange behavior. You wanted CCleaner to _not_ remove the files right? Unchecking that setting is what is supposed to work. However, if that setting is already unchecked then I would try to check it and then uncheck again. It's like when you have a hardware problem and you slap the monitor only to find that it worked, or when you have a problem with windows then you restart the OS. My guess is that you came across some kind of a bug in CCleaner and toggling that setting fixed it. Let me update my answer so that others can try to toggle, if it's already unchecked.

Comment: That makes sense. Having other issues and security concerns, I copy my active files to a memory stick and unplug it, last thing; run C-Cleaner (leaving the PC on 24/7 for WinMediaCentre recordings), and next day reopen the active files (now much faster with the Recent Files populated). Most days I restart in Safe Mode (when WMC isn't recording). Otherwise, my five main active xlsb files (4-8 MB each) get slower, and I've recently had wifi/interent drop out (only from the PC itself) till I reinstalled Chrome (FireFox was better but I prefer Bookmarking in Chrome). All's working now. Thank you.

Comment: @iSeeker Since I use the ESR version of Firefox I can say with certainty that Chrome is better in terms of running page java scripts properly. I've seen a couple of occasions when websites will refuse to work in FF but work fine in Chrome. Also, FF tends to be a bit bloaty as you keep using it over a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I see mixed views on Firefox vs Chrome; e.g. my online bank has recently blamed login problems on Chrome rather than its own site.